# Pull out Recent 10 Records by Date from Datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I have a datatable, which has Id, Date, and Name... Its like a recent list... 
and I will keep adding records in it,,, But I want to save only Last 10 Records (Recent Dates) from it to an XML file,,, How can I pullout only 10 records ORDER BY Date ???

```
        DataRow recent_dr = recent_index.NewRow();
        recent_dr["Id"] = RosterId;
        recent_dr["Date"] = DateTime.Now;
        recent_dr["Name"] = Name;
        recent_index.Rows.Add(recent_dr);

        //recent_index.Select(" What to do here ?? 
        recent_index.WriteXml(s + "\\chats\\index.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

using limit key word will do the trick.

> SELECT * FROM yourDatabase
>       ORDER BY Date
>       LIMIT 10;

Comment: in that case you could use  the Take(10); method.